# Multiple facets in Apache Solr search not working

Tags: apache, url, solr

I'm trying to get multiple facets to work in Apache Solr search, however it doesn't seem to be working. I would like a logical OR and a logical AND to work - so that whenever anything in any of the categories shows up, it shows in the search. This is the URL string I am trying to use:

```
http://domain.com/en-US/resource-library?fq=sm_field_resource_type%3A(Datasheets%20OR%20Manuals)
```

And here are the individual ones:

```
http://domain.com/en-US/resource-library?f[0]=sm_field_resource_type%3ADatasheets

http://domain.com/en-US/resource-library?f[0]=sm_field_resource_type%3AManuals
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I change this so that it works correctly?

Comment: Would it possible to explain what is "resource-library" and what is f[0]? none of these urls look like solr web API.

Comment: I don't find that you are using Solr Faceting. Your queries look different. It doesn't look like standard Solr query.